# Unable to read date from excel in php

Tags: php, excel, date

Can someone help me to find what is wrong with the following code...These are the dates i have in my excel `26-1-2013` `28-12-2013` but it prints `1970-01-01`.

I tried different functions like date_create and date_modify but nothing works I've used date fun in my prog but its not working .

```
 <?php
include("excel/reader.php");
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
$data->read($_POST['upload']);
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("omega",$conn);
mysql_query($a);
for ($x = 2; $x <= count($data->sheets[0]["cells"]); $x++) 
{
$inv = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][1];
$ds = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][2];
echo "ds=".$ds;
echo "<br>";
$dos= date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$ds)));
echo "$dos=".$dos;
echo "<br>";
$ptname = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][3];
$bal = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][4];
$proname = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][5];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO sheet (INV,DOS,PTNAME,BAL,PROV)
VALUES ('$inv','$dos','$ptname','$bal','$proname')";
mysql_query($sql);
}
  ?>
```

Comment: i am getting the following OUTPUT:
41300=41300
1970-01-01=1970-01-01
41636=41636
1970-01-01=1970-01-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value that you're reading is actually an MS Excel timestamp, typically the number of days since 1st January 1900 (though it could be number of days since 1st January 1904 if the spreadsheet is using the Mac 1904 calendar)

You need to convert this to a Unix Timestamp in order to use PHP date functions with it.... depending on which Calendar is being used, a quick and dirty conversion:

**Windows 1900 Calendar**

```
$unixTimestamp = ($excelTimestamp - 25569) * 86400;
```

and for the reverse

```
$excelTimestamp = ($unixTimestamp / 86400) + 25569;
```

**Mac 1904 Calendar**

```
$unixTimestamp = ($excelTimestamp - 24107) * 86400;
```

and for the reverse

```
$excelTimestamp =  ($unixTimestamp / 86400) + 24107;
```

So MS Excel `41300` => `$unixTimestamp = (41300 - 25569) * 86400;` giving `1359158400` which is the unix timestamp for `26th January 2013`

Comment: Yes sir now $unixTimestamp returns the value 1359158400 what function i can use to convert it into the form 2013-01-26

Comment: if i use DateTime::cretaeFromFormat prob ll be solved but the issue is i m using php 5.2.2 it doesn't support createFromFormat is there any replacement for this function in php version 5.2.2

Comment: `1359158400` is a Unix timestamp, so you can simply use the standard PHP [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function: `echo date('Y-m-d', $unixTimestamp);`

Answer (score 2):

Those dates are not in a [format that can be interpreted by `strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). You will need to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to interpret those dates before you can convert them to a new format.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', '26-1-2013');
$dos = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: to use DateTime is have to include IOFactory.php right?

Comment: No. It is a built in PHP class.

Comment: no. RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php  datetime has been a core php library since 5.2.0

Comment: i am getting this erreo:- Call to undefined method DateTime::createfromformat()

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: You're out of luck then. This was introduced in PHP 5.3. You should consider upgrading as that version has been obsolete for a long time.

Comment: @Peter What platform are you presently running under? Windows, Linux, Mac? - Xampp, Mamp, Wamp, other? Home computer, hosted site?

Comment: OS-windows, Wamp server, Home computer

Comment: Just install a newer version of PHP. They make it easy to do.

Comment: i have already done some programs in my system and created few databases will they be affected because of upgrading

Comment: They should not be affected